# docker run without entry point

Tags: docker, docker-entrypoint

Could we have a {docker run} command without a entry point?
As far as I can see, there must be an entry point (if not specified, it should be defaulted to "bash" at most cases). Otherwise, I cannot have an image running as an container.

Let say I install Linux at my physical machine.
There is a background service running at background, listening on a port and then doing something.
Before I login, there is no bash shell running and I can still call the background service from another machine by the name and port.

Can I do something similar by {docker run}? That mean, I do not need an entry point (or the entry point is a system process instead of bash?) and just let the container system together with its background services up and running.

Answer (score 11):

If you `docker run` a container without any special entrypoint or command options, it runs the single command specified by its image's `ENTRYPOINT` and `CMD` directives.  This should be the usual way you run a container.  For example:

```sh
# Launches a PostgreSQL server, without manually specifying a command
docker run \
  -d -p 5432:5432 -v pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data \
  postgres:14
```

Anything you put after the image name overrides the `CMD` in the image.  You can use this for various sorts of useful debugging, or to run multiple containers off the same code base.

```sh
docker build -t django-image .

# What's in that image?
docker run --rm django-image \
  ls -l /app

# Get an interactive shell in a temporary container
docker run --rm -it django-image \
  bash

# Launch the Django server normally
docker run -d --name web -p 8000:8000 django-image

# Also launch a Celery worker off that same image
docker run -d --name worker django-image \
  celery worker
```

You should not normally need the `docker run --entrypoint` option.  Since it is a Docker option, it needs to appear *before* the image name, and any options it takes appear in the "command" slot *after* the image name.

```sh
# This syntax is awkward, design to avoid it
docker run --rm \
  --entrypoint ls \
  django-image \
  -l /app
```

In your Dockerfile `ENTRYPOINT` is totally optional.  Prefer setting the `CMD` and not `ENTRYPOINT` if you think you'll ever need any of the command-override forms suggested above, including debugging during initial development.

```sh
# no ENTRYPOINT
CMD python ./manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

Do not set `ENTRYPOINT` to an interpreter like `python` and put the rest of the command in `CMD`; this apparently works but limits commands to only things that are Python scripts, so you're forced into the awkward `docker run --entrypoint` setup for anything else.

If you do set `ENTRYPOINT`, the setup I find most useful is to have it be a wrapper shell script that does some initial setup, then ends with `exec "$@"` to run whatever the `CMD` is.  This works even with the various command-override forms, which still run the wrapper script but then run the user-provided command at the end.  The Dockerfile `ENTRYPOINT` line *must* be a JSON array ("exec syntax") for this to work.

My one exception to this is when building micro-images for Go programs that literally contain nothing besides the compiled program itself.  There is neither a shell nor any other tools in the image, and it's impossible to do anything besides run the one program.  In that case only, I'll set `ENTRYPOINT` to the path to the compiled binary; it still must be a JSON array.

Answer (score -2):

You don't need any entry point to run the docker image. you can run the image following the command. If your dockerfile contains entry point by default then remove it.

```
docker run image_name
```

Also share the docker file here, which might help people to answer better of your question.